# Syntax error while created sql table

Tags: java, sql

I am trying to create  following table, but i continiously getting error. It is seems for me that Java Db tries to parse "create table ORDER" as "ORDER BY". I lso tried to type "CREATE TABLE" but, as expected, no result. How it is possible to solve that problem?

```
public void createTable() throws SQLException {
        String createString = "create table ORDER "
                + "(ORDER_ID int  NOT NULL, " + "ORDER_NUMBER int NOT NULL, "
                + "PERSON_ID int NOT NULL, " + "PRIMARY KEY (ORDER_ID), "
                + "FOREIGN KEY (PERSON_ID) REFERENCES PERSON (PERSON_ID))";
        Statement stmt = null;
        System.out.println(createString);
        try {

            DatabaseMetaData meta = con.getMetaData();
            ResultSet tables = meta.getTables(null, null, "ORDER",
                    new String[] { "TABLE2" });
            int size = 0;
            while (tables.next()) {
                size++;
            }
            if (size == 0) {
                System.out.println("table created");
                stmt = con.createStatement();
                stmt.executeUpdate(createString);

            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("No connection");
            e.printStackTrace();
            // TODO make exeption
        } finally {
            if (stmt != null) {
                stmt.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

error

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "ORDER" at line 1, column 14.

    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at com.tuto.p4.OrderTable.createTable(OrderTable.java:38)
    at com.tuto.p4.Main.main(Main.java:18)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Синтаксическая ошибка: Encountered "ORDER" at line 1, column 14.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: ERROR 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "ORDER" at line 1, column 14.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.ParserImpl.parseStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepMinion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.prepareInternalStatement(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do believe "ORDER" is a reserved word so you should not be using it as a table name or column name. Try simple synonyms that describe the your function, like "POSITION" or "SORTED", etc.  Good luck!

EDIT: IF you really must use that word, you can try wrapping it in quotes like

```
create table `ORDER`
```

to force the sql engine to try and read it as a string.

Comment: Yeah, change of name works. Unfortunaly the task - to create table ORDER

Comment: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Lexical error at line 1, column 15.  Encountered: "`" (96), after : "". So, `ORDER` also does not work

Comment: The righ answer - suround word with "", I to use reserved name as a table or row name type "NAME"

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use brackets like this to create your table:

```
create table `ORDER` ...
```

Comment: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "\'ORDER\'" at line 1, column 15.

Comment: ' is not the same as ` !